# PDO update issue

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update

I'm trying to write a bit of a controller to do some CRUD with PDO and have this issue where nothing happens and doesn't throw. I am pretty sure i am binding correctly but after dumping out, I can't see any issues with this and the table doesn't update.

Can someone please have a look?.

```
public function update($query, $array)
{
    try
    {
        $stm = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        foreach($array AS $key=>$value)
        {
            if(gettype($value) == "integer")
            {
                $stm->bindParam($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            if(gettype($value) == "string")
            {
                $stm->bindParam($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }

        }
        $stm->execute();

        return ($stm->rowCount()<=0) ? FALSE : $stm->rowCount();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Error with the query on line: ' . __LINE__ . ' in file: ' . __FILE__;
    }       
}   

$test = new SQL('127.0.0.1', 'test', '*************', 'mike_test');
$pull = $test->update('UPDATE names SET name=:name WHERE id=:id;',[':name'=>'James',':id'=>2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `bindParam()` which binds to a variable, and since you bind each parameter to the same variable (`$value`), you essentially use the last value for all parameters.

Solution: use `bindValue()`.

> I can't see any issues with this and the table doesn't update.

Then the ID value doesn't match anything in the table, as it did update on my test system.

Answer (score 0):

You just made you code too bloated. But there is a rule: the more code you write, the more errors you introduce. So make this function this way

```
public function update($query, $array)
{
    $stm = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stm->execute($array);
    return $stm->rowCount();
}
```